# C# Datatable: Computing the average in a column

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumn

I'm trying to get the average P&L in a column. The column is of type double, however I keep getting an error saying the following:

Additional information: Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.

This occurs when this line is executing:

```
avgFiveSbefore = (double)dt.Compute("AVG(5sBeforePnL)", "");
```

Also, here's some additional code to clarify:

```
dt.Columns.Add(Columns.FiveSecBeforePnL, typeof(double));

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  row[Columns.FiveSecBeforePnL] = some value;
}

double avgFiveSbefore;
avgFiveSbefore = (double)dt.Compute("AVG(5sBeforePnL)", "");
```

Comment: Could you try changing the column name to something that doesn't start with a number?  Just thinking that might be the cause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try enclosing the column name in square brackets.

```
avgFiveSbefore = (double)dt.Compute("AVG([5sBeforePnL])", "");
```

You can also use LINQ to do the same like:

```
double avgFiveSbefore = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .Average(r =>
                                r.Field<double>(Columns.FiveSecBeforePnL));
```